# nesting another field in a json column with a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to use the Json type available in the Postgres 9.2 release as a means to store a variety of data in one field. I created a column called `data` of json type on the `corrections` table. The form is a regular rails form except that the number of form fields it creates depends on the length of a `@content array` like this

```
 <%= f.fields_for :data, @correction.data do |d| %>
  <%  @content.each do |content| %>    
       <%= d.text_area content, :class => 'content', :value => "", :cols => "40", :rows => "2", :id => 'correction_data_'"#{content.parameterize}"%>
 <% end -%>
<%= end %>
```

If the @content array, had two elements, the database entry for data would look like this

```
data: {"key from @content"=>"value entered in form field", "key from @content" => "value entered in form field }
```

I have two questions

1 How would I change the Rails form to nest another key value pair inside (or associate with) each key value pair

```
"key from @content"=>"value entered in form field"
```

For example, I'm wondering if there's a way to nest or associate a comment field inside this data column for each key/value pair like this

```
 "key from @content"=>"value entered in form field"  comment key => comment value
 "key from @content"=>"value entered in form field"  comment key => comment value
```

2 Is this proper JSON format? It seems to me like it's just saving a bunch of key value pairs with the key always changing depending on the `content from @content`. If it isn't, is that a problem? Am I missing out on something by doing it this way?

```
 data: {"content from @content"=>"value entered in form field", "content from @content" => "value entered in form field }
```

Comment: Are you mixing up `json` and `hstore`? Your notation looks ... peculiar.

Comment: @CraigRinger I agree that it looks peculiar, but I thought it was just because the way I had the form set up. This is the migration for the column  `t.json     "data"` so it's not hstore

Comment: I just checked and that code is nonsense; JSON is formatted as `{key: value}` pairs, not `{key=>value}`.

Comment: @CraigRinger ok, thanks, it looked wrong to me.  I can confirm however that the `type` for the `data` column is `json` and looking at the records in the Rails console shows that it's stored as a key value with the arrow:  `data: {"foo"=>"bar"`

Comment: OK, so what you're quoting is the Ruby dictionary/hash, and you expect ActiveRecord to translate it to JSON for storage. Fair enough, but means this is way above the database level so time for me to run away.